# JPA Spring OneToMany ManyToOne Collection Empty

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

**Infos**

Spring 3.1.2 / Kotlin 1.9.10

**Code**

```
@Entity
data class Parent(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = -1,
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    val children: List<Child>? = arrayListOf()
)


@Entity
data class Child(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = -1,
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true) @JoinColumn(name = "fk_parent") // owns the foreign keys
    val parent: Parent? = null
)

@Repository
interface ParentRepository : JpaRepository<Parent, Long>

@Repository
interface ChildRepository : JpaRepository<Child, Long>
```

**Test with H2 and PostGres Dialect**

```
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest(classes = [Application::class], webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
internal class ParentRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var parentRepository: ParentRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var childRepository: ChildRepository

    @Test
    fun test() {
        var parent = parentRepository.saveAndFlush(Parent())
        childRepository.saveAndFlush(Child().copy(parent = parent))
        parent = parentRepository.findById(parent.id).get() // don't do this at home, kids
        Assertions.assertNotNull(parent.children)
        Assertions.assertTrue(parent.children!!.isNotEmpty()) // fails
    }
}
```

**Question**

When running the test field of parent containing the children is always empty. But I want to use the list of the children.

Comment: Generally, you want to use only one. Either ManyToOne or OneToMany. Why do you need both? `Parent` seems to be the aggregate. Just omit the parent field in the child and fetch the children always by the parent.

Comment: Since child is owning the foreign key, your comment is not quiet right: I should omit the child in the parent, and fetch the children using the parent id using the fk column. But It want to make both work - so instead of asking "Why both" - I would like to get help for the question: What do I have to do, to make it work.

Comment: You can't make it work. Assume this: If you fetch the list of children when you fetch a parent, then you would have to fetch all child entities as well. Those child entities then, would have their own child entities fetched (immediately). What you need is a lazy list, one that only fetches it's entities, once they are accessed, but this is (often) a very bad pattern, as it causes unexpected DB-calls in situations where you don't expect them, and depending on the implementation, you either fetch one, or all entities, either which can be inefficient, if generalized.

Comment: @Mr.Mountain for a relational DB you just need one of those relations. I'd add an FK in the child but have a `@OneToMany` at the parent combined with `@JoinColumn(name = "parent_fk", nullable = false)`

Comment: But this would create a new column at the parent 'parent_fk' referencing the child. The relation should stay unidirectional. But the retrieval should collect the reference.

Comment: I don't see any problems with your mappings - this a standard bidirectional OneToMany relationship. It is also the standard problem with bidirectional relationships - your application is only setting the ManyToOne side of things. JPA maintains a cache of managed entities, so every find call on the parent will return the managed instance. As these are just java objects, the Parent collection will never show the children referencing it if you don't set the references to keep the object in synch with the database; that is until it is refreshed or re-loaded from the database.

Comment: In short: add the child to the parent.children list when adding new children is the easiest solution. If you don't/can't do that, the other alternative is to force a refresh on the parent instance using em.refresh(parent), which will cause it to re fetch the children collection from the database with the current state.

Comment: Ok - so JPA will not fetch the children and I have to do it manually. Right? If so, please provide a nice answer for the next JPA solution seeking developer and I will accept the answer.